# Regex expression help needed to filter filenames in Mirth Connect

Tags: regex, mirth-connect

I need a way, in a Mirth file reader channel, to pick up all files but one with a given name.  I can use a regex expression in the Filename Filter Pattern box.

Most files are of the format #######.brf.   I need to pick up any file that isn't named 0050450.brf. Can someone help with this?

Thanks
Rut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one should work: `^(?!(0050450\.brf))\w*\.brf`

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code. I realize it's a short and simple solution, but code-only answers are still frowned upon in any case.